# Syntax: assign method's property value to sql command

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I've got method:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getTheCountriesEurope:(int)continentID
{
NSMutableArray* euCountriesArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
const char* sqlContinents="SELECT countries.countryID,countries.countryName\
FROM countries\
WHERE countries.relativeToContinentID=?";
```

How can I assign to sql command my (int)continentID property? I mean to statement

```
WHERE countries.relativeToContinentID=?";
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
formattedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:
    @"SELECT countries.countryID,countries.countryName\
    FROM countries\
    WHERE countries.relativeToContinentID=%i"
    ,continentID];
```

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way is to use [sqlite3_prepare_v2()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) to compile your SQL statement and then use [sqlite3_bind_int()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to bind your int parameter to the statement.  This is better than putting the int into the SQL query string because

1. the statement can be reused with different int parameters
2. Using prepare/bind prevents any chance of a [SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/).  While this isn't a problem for int parameters, it is a headache for strings and you might as well do everything the same way.

Comment: Thank you I'll return to this topic in few days. At moment I have another headache - how to transfer continentID to third view.

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, can you point me to some professional emplementation example?

Comment: @Nathan: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/sqlite/bind_insert.html uses an insert, but the principle is the same.